# How do I access Windows files from Linux Mint (and vice-versa if possible)? I have dual boot

Tags: partition, partition-table

I have dual boot with Windows 10 and Linux Mint 19.1

Comment: Just a note that from the windows side you will need to disable "fast startup" which hibernates when you think it has shutdown.  This prevents drives being read by other operating systems.

Answer (score 4):

In Linux: Open your file manager. The side-bar should display the Windows partitions. Click on them.

In Windows: I recommend [EXT2FSD](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) as mentioned [here](https://superuser.com/questions/37512/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-on-windows) or [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9933/how-to-read-ext4-partitions-in-windows).

In the long run, I recommend creating a partition specifically for sharing files between operating systems. For this task, I prefer UDF as a file-system as it supports symlinks in both os'es, but exFAT and NTFS are fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

As Hermann said in linux you can check it from your file manager, however you need to **turn off the fast start up from windows** otherwise it give you an error that cannot mount the partition.

In windows i use [DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://www.diskinternals.com/linux-reader/) which is really friendly.

Regards

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. [Please review the Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) for more information regarding this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but here's the answer for Linux Mint v20.1.  If opening the Files app does NOT show your windows partition, then it means it isn't mounted.  Right-click the Files (file manager) app and instead of choosing the default of Home, choose Computer instead. This defaults to a view of both mounted and unmounted file systems.  Double-click the file system/hard drive/partition that contains your Windows boot record - This mounts it as a folder.  NOW you can use the Files app to browse your Windows partition (or hard drive).  You can unmount by right-clicking the partition in the tree view of Files and select Unmount.  Note that it likely stays in the list but becomes inaccessible.  Closing and reopening Files removes it from the list.

Answer (score 0):

First off all check the available storage devices with the following command:

```
lsblk
```

You can identify the file system with option -f:

```
lsblk -f
```

Identify the storage device that corresponds with your Windows.

Create a directory to access the content of your Windows partition or disk:

```
sudo mkdir /media/windows
```

Then you should mount the partition doing something similar to the the following:

```
sudo mount /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

Where sda3 is the partition and could be different in your case, and /media/windows is the mountpoint that we just created.

If you encounter a problem, can try using the explicit options:

First you need to validate your id with id command:

```
id
```

Then could do something like:

```
sudo mount -t ntfs-3g -o uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=002,fmask=111 /dev/sda3 /media/windows
```

This solution is temporary. If you want to automount your file system when the system boots you must modify the file:

```
/etc/fstab
```

If you are from the GUI you can also use try choosing the partition in the file manager.